# Latex distribution new installed, error undefined control sequence always occurs when moderncv is used

Tags: errors

I installed protext distribution on another pc and tried to edit my cv. Unfortunately this error message does appear and I do not know why?

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("E:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("E:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \@lastname 

l.247 \makelettertitle
```

This is my reduced code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}               
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[firstyear=1996,lastyear=2014.34]{moderntimeline}
\usepackage{eurosym}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}

% distance of entries to date column

\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{2.5em}

% Suppress final dot in \cventry
\renewcommand*\cventry[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

% New page style
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
\fancyhead[L]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\sffamily\footnotesize
adress\\adress}}
\fancyhead[C]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\fixedphonesymbol\sffamily\footnotesize phone}}
\fancyhead[R]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\emailsymbol\sffamily\footnotesize  mail}}
}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@myfancy
\let\ps@empty\ps@myfancy
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myfancy}

% Redefinitions of \makecvtitle, opening and closing to
% have the desired formatting for first and family names
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname}\par\smallskip\namestyle{\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[3em]%
  {\bfseries\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vfill%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    \raggedleft%
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname\\\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
12 March 2014, place\\[2em]% US
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}

\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother


% for timeline

\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\NewDocumentCommand\tldatelabelcventryn{O{center}O{color1}mmmmmmm}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{\tl@lastyear}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#3-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline]{%
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \fill [#2] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,yshift=5pt,anchor=#1] {#4}
        node {$\bullet$};
   }
}
{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}
}
\newcommand\tllabelcventryn[9][color1]{%
  \gdef\Argi{#1}%
  \gdef\Argii{#2}%
  \gdef\Argiii{#3}%
  \gdef\Argiv{#4}%
  \gdef\Argv{#5}%
  \gdef\Argvi{#6}%
  \gdef\Argvii{#7}%
  \gdef\Argviii{#8}%
  \gdef\Argix{#9}%
  \auxtllabelcventryn
}
\def\auxtllabelcventryn#1{%
  \gdef\Argx{#1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{ifthenelse(\Argiii==0,\tl@lastyear,\Argiii)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(\Argii-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline=0pt]{
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\Argi] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,anchor=north east] {\Argiv} node [tl@startyear,above] {\Argv}
        rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt);
     \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\Argiii} \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt
        \shade [left color=\Argi] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \else
        \fill [\Argi] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \fi
     }
}
{\Argvi}{\Argvii}{\Argviii}{\Argix}{\Argx}%
}
\makeatother
%
\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

\firstname{prr}
\familyname{sr}
\title{Curriculum vit\ae{}}              
\address{}{}  
\photo[128pt]{picture}                        


\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
}%
\item[]}
{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

This is my cv.

\end{document}
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("E:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("E:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty"))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...a \@parboxrestore \fixedphonesymbol 
                                                  \sffamily \footnotesize ph...
l.238 \end{document}
```

I do not know where the problem is? I installed everything correctly and updated the package moderncv. Is gettitlestring.sty causing the error? What should I do?

When I run this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}               
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[firstyear=1996,lastyear=2014.34]{moderntimeline}
\usepackage{eurosym}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

This is my cv.

\end{document}
```

I get the error message:

```
Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("E:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("E:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))

Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagelabels' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 20.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname 
                       {}~\@familyname {}
l.20 \begin{document}
```

Whats wrong with my latex?

Ok, I now think this is a problem with the moderncv package, when I run this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

\begin{document}
test

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("E:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("E:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))

Package hyperref Warning: Option `pdfpagelabels' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 3.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname 
                       {}~\@familyname {}
l.3 \begin{document}

?
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I am unable to produce an error when running your code -- possibly because there is no `\makelettertitle` macro being executed. Please review your code and tweak it so that it actually produces the problem behavior you would like to see fixed.

Comment: @Mico I now pinned it to the current problem. It seems to me that it has not anything to do with the makelettertitle macro. So something else is wrong with my whole latex distribution?!

Comment: I see you run MikTeX. How long ago did you install it, and are you able to compile other LaTeX files correctly? If not, your MikTeX installation may be broken and may need to be reinstalled from scratch.

Comment: @Mico I can run this example: http://www.electronics.oulu.fi/latex/examples/example_1/ But I cannot run anything with the moderncv package, I edited my question.

Comment: When I try to run the template.tex from this example here http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples I also have the ! Undefined control sequence. error problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a faulty installation of the TeX system

Comment: To get the `\@firstname` and `\@lastname` defined, you need something like `\name{Karl}{Marx}` in your file. However, `\fixedphonesymbol` should already be defined. I suspect you may have an older version of `moderncv.cls`.